# Правильное употребление тире в составном именном сказуемом

Tags: пунктуация

**Лес — прекрасное выражение силы природы и самый ясный образчик, её совершенства. Охранять природу, значит, охранять родину.**

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: Охранять природу значит охранять родину. Значение равносильности, приравненности, тире не ставится, запятой нет. (Запятая ставится только при обособлении вводного слова  ЗНАЧИТ,стиль разговорный, значение "следовательно, стало быть").

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Со связкой ЗНАЧИТ всё не так просто, здесь надо обращаться к словарю:

ЗНАЧИТЬ  1. что, с инф. или с придат. дополнит. Иметь какой-л. смысл, означать (о словах, знаках, жестах и т. п.). Имя Виктор значит победитель.  2.Иметь значение, быть важным, существенным; играть роль. Его обещание значит много, 3. только 3 л.: значит, значило. (употр. в зн. СВЯЗКИ).То же, что; всё равно, что. Простить значит забыть.

ЗНАЧИТ, вводн. сл. Разг.Следовательно, стало быть. От воды идёт пар, значит, вода теплее воздуха. Вещи собраны, значит, уезжаете?

ЗНАЧИТ, союз.
Таким образом, следовательно. Тучи собираются, значит будет дождь. Ты сердишься, значит  ты не прав. < А значит; и значит, союз.И поэтому, стало быть, следовательно. Проезжаю родные места, и значит увижу своих племянников.

Еще из Грамматики 80. Там выделяется пять значений для таких предложений, и тире не ставится в двух случаях: А) Равносильность, приравненность: Писать языком разговорным значит не знать языка. Б) условно-следственная связь: Услышать хорошую песню значит воспрять духом. При значениях сущности, идентичности и сравнения тире ставится.

ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНОЕ ПОЯСНЕНИЕ: Выбираем:  глагол «значит» или связку «значит».

А. НЕ СТАВИМ ТИРЕ, если  строим  СООТНОШЕНИЕ «ЗНАК – ЗНАЧЕНИЕ». В этом случае используется глагол. Проверочное соотношение: ЭТО ОЗНАЧАЕТ, ЭТО СВИДЕТЕЛЬСТВУЕТ.

1) Равносильность, приравненность.  Писать  только языком разговорным значит не знать языка (это является знаком того, что ты не знаешь языка).

2) Условно-следственная связь. Сделаться смешным значит потерять многое (это будет знаком того, что ты потерял многое).

Б. СТАВИМ ТИРЕ, если ЗНАЧЕНИЯ СОВПАДАЮТ: значение 1= значению 2.  В этом случае используется связка.  Проверочное соотношение: ЭТО ВСЕ РАВНО ЧТО.

1) ТОЖДЕСТВО, ИДЕНТИЧНОСТЬ, СОВПАДЕНИЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЙ: Быть милосердным – это значит быть справедливым. Думать о будущем – это значит думать о будущем своих детей.

2) СУЩНОСТЬ. Доказать – значит убедить. Уметь слушать – это не значит только уметь молчать.

3) СРАВНЕНИЕ. Не ответить на письмо -  это значит (все равно что) не пожать протянутую руку.

РЕШЕНИЕ:
Охранять природу ? значит охранять Родину.

(1) Охранять природу – значит (это все равно что) охранять Родину (это однозначные понятия).
(2) Охранять природу значит охранять Родину. (Охрана природы  свидетельствует о том, что ты охраняешь Родину. Но это не однозначные понятия).

Comment: Не могли бы Вы пояснить, чем идентичность отличается от равносильности.

Comment: Ларf, развернутое объяснение того, как я понимаю эту тему, я поместила в ответе. Если кратко ответить на Ваш вопрос, тополучится следующее. Идентичность - это совпадение значений (это все равно что). Равносильность, приравненность - это соотношение знак-значение.

Comment: Такое впечатление, что мы разные грамматики читали. В Грамматике-80 не сказано, что постановка тире зависит от того, какая из пяти перечисленных семантических структур представлена. Там просто описываются эти структуры. Более того, НА ОДНИ И ТЕ ЖЕ СТРУКТУРЫ ДАЮТСЯ ПРИМЕРЫ С ТИРЕ И БЕЗ НЕГО. 
Квалификация по идентичности:  Быть милосердным – значит быть справедливым; Толстеть значит стареть. 
Квалификация по равносильности, приравненности:  Писать единственно языком разговорным значит не знать языка; Делать искусство – значит также производить ценности.

Comment: Квалификация по сущности: Доказать – значит убедить.  Тут пример один.
Квалификация по условно-следственной связи:  Услышать хорошую песню значит воспрянуть духом; Спешить по глубокому снегу - значит в несколько минут запыхаться. 
Квалификация на основании сравнения, сопоставления:  связка «значит» для таких предложений ВООБЩЕ НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ.

Answer (score 1):

Охранять природу - (это) значит, охранять родину. Перед подразумеваемым "это" в данном и в подобных случаях надо ставить "тире"

Answer (score 0):

Согласно правилам пунктуации единственно правильный вариант выглядит так:

Лес - прекрасное выражение силы природы и самый ясный образчик её совершенства. Охранять природу - значит охранять родину.

При инфинитиве *значит* всегда связка.

В данном вопросе официальные правила пунктуации не совпадают с примерами из Грамматики-80. Можно сколько угодно рассуждать на эту тему, но отсутствие тире будет считаться ошибкой.

Comment: Tat, немного странное выступление. Вы как на уроке математики хотите написать правильный ответ, не решая задачи, и ожидаете, что Вас за это похвалят. Во-первых, пунктуация основана на семантическом и грамматическом принципах, поэтому и рассуждать никогда не вредно, и с Грамматикой-80  не должно быть расхождений. Во-вторых, НИКАКИХ РАСХОЖДЕНИЙ И НЕТ, потому что на официальном сайте Грамота.ру  можно  ознакомиться с примером, в котором тире между двумя инфинитивами перед  «значит» отсутствует: «Простить значит забыть».

Comment: И наконец, по существу. Мне, как и многим  другим, хочется поставить тире в предложении «Охранять природу – значит охранять Родину», очень симпатично оно там смотрится. И вот, исходя из приведенных рассуждений, я могу себе позволить это, для чего делаю проверку:   «Охранять природу – значит (ЭТО ВСЕ РАВНО ЧТО)  охранять Родину». Возможно, именно такую патетику вкладывал сюда автор суждения, а некоторую условность этого тождества вполне  можно отнести к художественным средствам выразительности. Получается, что здесь возможны оба решения.

Comment: В то же время в других случаях такую подстановку сделать нельзя, что свидетельствует о том, что тире там совершенно не к месту, например: «простить»  – это не все равно что «забыть», здесь нет совпадения значений, но есть знак, которому приписывается определенное значение.  И ВЫВОД: рассуждая и анализируя, вы любой аудитории можете  представить свое аргументированное решение и обсудить проблему, в противном  же случае становитесь заложником одной точки зрения, которую Вы к тому же не всегда можете доказать.

Comment: София, я просто отвечаю на вопрос "Как правильно расставить знаки?", а не "Как логично с точки зрения грамматики?" или "Как должно быть по справедливости?". И с чего вы взяли, что я ожидаю за это похвалы? Ваш пресловутый пример "Простить значит забыть", взятый якобы с Грамота.ру, на самом деле из ТОЛКОВОГО словаря Кузнецова, который на этом сайте действительно есть. Но толковый словарь не является экспертным в вопросах пунктуации и орфографии. В словаре Кузнецова МОРЕ орфографических ошибок, так почему бы там не быть и пунктуационным? Я уже заметила несколько.

Comment: Что касается позиции портала Грамота.ру, она однозначна: при инфинитиве "значит" связка и отделяется тире. Отсутствие тире - ошибка. Таковы правила пунктуации со времен языковой реформы. Правило может измениться, но пока этого не произошло. Вы часто отвечаете на вопросы как исследователь, как будто обсуждаете вопрос с научным сообществом. И забываете о том, что вопросы задают и простые носители языка, которые хотят знать, как правильно (от слова "правило").

Comment: Tat, прежде чем на что-то ответить, я захожу на сайт "Грамота-ру", считая, что именно он представляет официальную орфографию. Вы также зайдите, укажите в поисковике глагол ЗНАЧИТЬ, и вот ответ: "ЗНАЧИТЬ. 3. только 3 л.: ЗНАЧИТ, ЗНАЧИЛО. (употр. в зн. связки).
То же, что; всё равно, что. Простить значит забыть. Забить ещё гол значило выиграть первенство мира".

Comment: София, таким образом вы выходите в толковый словарь Кузнецова. Зайдите в Справочник по пунктуации на Грамоте (он дублирует печатный словарь-справочник "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации") или наберите "значит" в строке "Поиск ответа" (не в строке "Проверка слова") - и увидите ответы Грамоты на аналогичные вопросы читателей. Толковый словарь на Грамоте служит своим целям. Чтобы проверить орфографию, нужно смотреть Орфографический словарь, а пунктуацию - Справочник по пунктуации.