# Ставятся ли тут запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Мой учитель профессор Николас Дрест.*

Comment: Это часть предложения или всё целиком?

Comment: Ответ будет зависеть от контекста.

Comment: @Людмила это часть предложения. Вот полное "Мой учитель профессор Николас Дрест, преподаватель в Венском университете.

Comment: Даже этого недостаточно. Нужен более широкий контекст.

Comment: @М_Г Я успешно, с энтузиазмом, изучаю социологию. Мой учитель, профессор Николас Дрест, преподаватель в Венском университете. Который определил понятие твёрдости характера, как - настойчивость и страсть к долгосрочным целям.

Comment: Юрий, очень жаль, что вопрос был задан в отрыве от контекста. Фразу можно было понять по-разному. В результате Вы получили — и приняли — неверный в данном контексте ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Запятая** после слова "учитель" **ставится**, поскольку слова "профессор Николай Дрест" являются **уточнением**, перед которым положено ставить запятую.

http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28

Answer (score 1):

Здесь тире.

***Мой учитель - профессор Николас Дрест.***

Если верить в точку в конце фразы, то "профессор Николай Дерст" никакое не уточнение, а именная часть составного сказуемого (с опущенным глаголом-связкой). Если очень захотеть, то можно переосмыслить грамматику, объявив предложение номинативным, и поставить эту запятую, но это пригодно разве что для подписи к фотографии - да и то лучше сто раз подумать, зачем это надо.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92
[Правильное употребление тире в составном именном сказуемом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33418)

Аааа... Посмотрел первую версию вопроса. Точка-то преткновения - результат посторонней  правки. Возможно, что её там и не предполагалось...
Ну тогда да, см. "Матвей Дёмин".

Answer (score 1):

> Я успешно, с энтузиазмом, изучаю социологию. Мой учитель, профессор Николас Дрест, преподаватель в Венском университете. Который определил понятие твёрдости характера, как - настойчивость и страсть к долгосрочным целям.

Мой вариант:

**Я успешно, с энтузиазмом изучаю социологию. Мой учитель — профессор Венского университета Николас Дрест, который определил понятие твёрдости характера как настойчивость и страсть к долгосрочным целям.**

### Пояснения

- Из контекста следует, что слова *профессор Николай Дерст* — не уточнение к "мой учитель", я именное сказуемое. Ведь предложение именно для того и составлено, чтобы сказать, кто является моим учителем.
- Слова *профессор Венского университета* дают полное преставление и о том, что он профессор, и о том, что преподает в Венском университете.
- Не вижу причин ставить запятую после слов *с энтузиазмом*. *Успешно*, *с энтузиазмом* — однородные определения. Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Казалось даже, что обман крайне необходим, что без него нельзя: все дружно, **с энтузиазмом** будут обманываться и обман воплотится в жизнь, станет действительностью. [Сергей Залыгин. Предисловие // «Новый Мир», 1998]
>
> Советские люди горячо, **с энтузиазмом** принялись за их выполнение. [В. Федотов. Здравствуй, восьмидесятый! // «Работница», 1980]